# Granite Devices Ioni Pro. PWM set point mode

Tags: motor

Inspecting the PWM set point mode it seems HSIN2 is the PWM input, and HSIN1 is the PWM direction input.  Is it possible to reverse this, so that it's more consistent with step and direction mode wiring?  I would like HSIN1 as the PWM input, and HSIN2 as the PWM direction.

Could the function of HSIN1, and HSIN2 be selected in Granity, once the setpoint type is chosen?

Most grateful for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to change the HSIN pin functions in Granity. We'll check if it's easily feasible to implement to the firmware.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's great to know the company is flexible.  I represent a company with over 1000 axes of motion.  I'm evaluating the Ioni Pro, and if all goes well, I'd like to contact Granite Devices directly.  Keep up the good work! :)